# I am using angular 9 (Ivy complier) and I need to display the pdf file in preview. For this i just want to use the ngx-doc-viewer but it showing error

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-doc-viewer

ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
200:181-193
Can't import the named export 'CommonModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
201:143-155
Can't import the named export 'CommonModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
205:30-42
Can't import the named export 'CommonModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
131:18-27
Can't import the named export 'Component' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
128:153-168
Can't import the named export 'DomSanitizer' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
172:58-73
Can't import the named export 'DomSanitizer' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
14:26-38
Can't import the named export 'EventEmitter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
175:22-27
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
177:22-27
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
179:22-27
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
181:22-27
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
183:22-27
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
185:22-27
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
187:22-27
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
189:22-27
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
191:22-27
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
129:2588-2595
Can't import the named export 'NgIf' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
203:18-26
Can't import the named export 'NgModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
128:181-190
Can't import the named export 'NgZone' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
172:85-94
Can't import the named export 'NgZone' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
173:22-28
Can't import the named export 'Output' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
193:22-34
Can't import the named export 'ViewChildren' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
48:15-24
Can't import the named export '__awaiter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
108:41-54
Can't import the named export 'getDocxToHtml' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
69:36-52
Can't import the named export 'getViewerDetails' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
75:36-52
Can't import the named export 'getViewerDetails' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
114:39-62
Can't import the named export 'googleCheckSubscription' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
120:22-36
Can't import the named export 'iframeIsLoaded' from non EcmaScript
module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
73:20-31
Can't import the named export 'isLocalFile' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
74:35-50
Can't import the named export 'replaceLocalUrl' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
128:203-221
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
199:149-167
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
130:0-27
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
202:0-27
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
129:29-52
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareComponent' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
128:29-50
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
199:26-47
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
201:26-48
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjector' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm2015/ngx-doc-viewer.mjs
200:26-48
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareNgModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue. I solved it by downgrading the ngx-doc-viewer version because my tslib had a lower version than what is required. Check to see if the ngx-doc-viewer version is compatible with your tslib version. Also check if you have the dependency docviewhelper. You can take a look at your package-lock.json for example to see what is required.

```
"ngx-doc-viewer": {
  "version": "2.1.2",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ngx-doc-viewer/-/ngx-doc-viewer-2.1.2.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-TuWSWGl1sCGe9w3oSiL93DeOr4JdCKb79ImnFv696AHi81zNFzwZs6RRV95nusoh6YTmBORra7D2oDDh6yeXWw==",
  "requires": {
    "docviewhelper": ">= 0.0.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
```

Another solution could be to remove the "^" in ngx-doc-viewer version in package.json. So do "ngx-doc-viewer": "2.1.2" instead of "ngx-doc-viewer": "^2.1.2".